# Advantages of the Doctor's new sonic device?

Tags: doctor-who

***UPDATE***: *Per comments below I see the flaw in my question now.*

---

In the Doctor Who episode *The Witch's Familiar*, we learn that
the Doctor has:

> traded in his sonic screwdriver for a pair of sonic sunglasses

Are there any technological advantages to utilizing this style of device or is it merely a cosmetic change, similar to each Doctor who has gone before him?

Further, what happened to his previous sonic screwdriver?

> Is this possibly the one that we find later in the hands of River Song?

Comment: You should probably ask these separately. The answer to the second is an emphatic "no", but the first one we don't have enough information to say yet

Comment: Personally I'm keeping my fingers crossed that he'll go back to the sonic screwdriver. Sunglasses WTF? Please don't let Capaldi become another "sunglasses are cool" Doctor!

Comment: It's an example of real science influencing science fiction, in this case, Google Glass

Comment: Trigger warning for, well, just about anyone — you can’t take a sonic screwdriver [into the shower](http://i1.wp.com/venturebeat.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/scoble-shower-google-glass.jpg?resize=803%2C602)!

Comment: The advantage is obviously that he can use the new device hands-free. Probably with his ears or something.

Comment: Oops, looks like you got lots of downvotes after my answer disproved your premise. Sorry about that! I upvoted (admittedly well before answering).

Comment: Not a problem. I rewatched the episode last night and caught the things you pointed out and thus see the flaws in my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Are there any technological advantages to utilizing this style of device or is it merely a cosmetic change, similar to each Doctor who has gone before him?

None that had been revealed as of S09E02. In the following episode, we see him use the glasses as a self contained wifi-enabled camera; a capability not established (nor refuted) for the screwdriver.

> Further, what happened to his previous sonic screwdriver?

Spoiler answer:

> He abandoned it at li'l Davros's feet in the handmine field. Davros kept it through the ensuing millenia.

Spoiler question:

> Is this possibly the one that we find later in the hands of River Song?

No. The events in question were portrayed in a DVD extra; they are well in The Doctor's past at this point.

Comment: Given the end of S9E2, are we SURE he abandoned his previous screwdriver?

Comment: There is a paradox in play if he didn't. That said, no.

Comment: Theres also the point that rivers sonic looks like a slightly modified 10's, while the one Capaldi lost is 11's and hugely different in appearance.

Comment: As for Series 9, episode 3, the sonic sun glasses have WiFi!!! You should add that to your answer @Politank-Z

Comment: @tilley31 Done, provisionally.

Answer (score 5):

Your first spoilertag says the Doctor has

> traded in his sonic screwdriver for a pair of sonic sunglasses.

**No he hasn't.** According to a [recent interview with Peter Capaldi](http://www.whatsontv.co.uk/tv-news/news/peter-capaldi-the-sonic-sunglasses-have-arrived-because-the-doctor-loves-ray-bans), the sonic sunglasses are not a replacement for the sonic screwdriver, but simply an extra add-on:

> "The Sonic Screwdriver hasn’t gone,” explains Peter Capaldi who plays the Doctor. “The Sonic Sunglasses are an adjunct to the Sonic Screwdriver and have arrived because the Doctor likes Ray-Bans! You press them and they go zzzzz and they do great things.”

Comment: “You press them and they go zzzzz and they do great things” — if only they’d had that marketing slogan, Google Glass might have taken off in the mainstream.